# How far out of the net can a goalie freeze the puck in the NHL?

Tags: rules, ice-hockey, nhl, goalkeeper

Hockey goalies wear glove on one hand to catch the puck. I've seen the goalies freeze the puck by putting their glove on the puck when it's on ice feet outside of the crease.

What are the goalie limitations to use their glove to freeze the puck or catch a shot? Where can the goalie not use is glove?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this deals with the flow of the game, and specifically rule 63 "delay of game penalty"

The explanation starts on  [page 88](http://1.cdn.nhle.com/downloads/2016-17_RuleBook.pdf) and describes that a goaltender may use his equipment in the defensive zone other than to intentionally delay the game in so far as he is being "checked" or influenced to do so by an opponent. A goal tender may not play the puck behind the goal line except for the area within the trapezoid directly behind the net as doing so would result in a minor penalty.